# Rails query for 'comma separated string' in array

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

This is for a rails site for articles. Articles have tags stored in 4 different fields - technology_tag, sub_segment_tag and couple more fields.
Each of these fields stores a comma separated string.

I have a method that return an array of tags for a given article(on show page) by combining the 4 comma separated string tag fields(@tags below).

On the article show page I have a query to get related articles, like so -

Article.regular.published.where('date > ?', '2018-01-01').order(date: :desc).where('sub_segment_tag IN (?) ', @tags).limit(3)

Eg:- If the currently viewed article has -
@tags = ["Wallet"]

Only articles with exactly one value in sub_segment_tag i.e. "Wallet" are matched.
I want it to match articles that have sub_segment_tag = "Wallet,Banking" and other values too.

Please let me know if this is possible.

Thanks

Comment: i would suggest reading [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) especially the section *"Help others reproduce the problem"*.. Ideally we need to have table structures, example data and expected result also see [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: The in expects a list of values separated by a comma, not a single value that happens to have a comma separated string as a value. The two may look similar, but are not the same.

Answer (score 0):

Use directly like operator to query. Because the value stored in the column is kind of string format. Below would return all sub_segment_tag which has 'Wallet'.

```
Article.regular.published.where('date > ?', '2018-01-01').order(date: :desc).where("sub_segment_tag LIKE (?)", '%Wallet%').limit(3)
```